# Overnight Term rate

Tags: sofr, overnight-rate

I have come across this page from `CME` which provides O/N rate for various terms:

https://www.cmegroup.com/market-data/cme-group-benchmark-administration/term-sofr.html

I am confused on this specification. What does 6m `SOFR` as 0.05144 mean? `SOFR` is essentially overnight rate, so for a given day (closing) I would expect only single quote.

Is there any calculation happening to derive this so called 6M rate for `SOFR`? What does the rate 0.05144 mean in practical sense?

Any insight is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

These are term rates as implied by SOFR futures trading on CME. See https://www.cmegroup.com/market-data/files/cme-term-sofr-reference-rates-benchmark-methodology.pdf, section 4, "Calculating Term Rates from SOFR Futures".

Comment: In particular, xM-SOFR is an ON SOFR rate compounded over x Months, according to formula un Sec 5 https://www.cmegroup.com/market-data/files/cme-term-sofr-reference-rates-benchmark-methodology.pdf

Comment: Thanks. One further question. CME publishes SOFR term rates for `1m`, `3m`, and `6m`. Given this information, is there any formula available to derive term rate for `4m` or more generally for `x` months?

Comment: You could interpolate between the 3m and 6m rates.

Comment: @user42108  is there any market convention for such interpolation designed for SOFR, to exclude any unintended possibilities like arbitrage opportunities etc?

Comment: Just to add my two cents on "interpolation"; without knowing the CME methdology in detail, IMO it's conceptually not really possible to disentangle this from the curve "bootstrap", especially for the compounding overnight rates. So given that you'd use these futures and/or OIS to build a SOFR *curve*, for a 4m SOFR "term rate" I'd simply use the 4m compound rate. Hence, capitalize (1 + the 3m compound rate) further for 1 more month, which is not the same as interpolating between a given 3m and 6m term rate.

Comment: @KevinT Your comments are helpful. However can you please tell more on how to `capitalize (1 + the 3m compound rate) further for 1 more month`, as you mentioned?

Comment: [1/2] To illustrate my point, it might help if you read [this thread about bootstrapping OIS curves](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/61838/). So unless your goal is using these CME "forward looking" rates implied in the futures on a daily basis as some sort of Libor-replacement fixing but rather to use the futures in the curve construction process, the daily spot/forward rates implied by those contracts can be used in any manner you want.

Comment: [2/2] So if the 3m rate defined as something like $(\Pi_{i=1}^{N} 1+r_i d_i - 1)*\dfrac{360}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}d_i}$, where $N$ is circa 90 days, $r_i$ are the daily overnight forwards rate from your curve, and $d_i$ are the daycount "weights" (usually 1/360 or 3/360), then nothing prevents you from using "30 more $r_i$'s" to obtain a 4 month term rate by using $N=120$ (roughly), which "*contains*" the pi product term for the first 90 estimates.