# Building SOFR curve - explanation of the formula used

Tags: libor, sofr

I am studying a previous post on how to build `SOFR` discount curve here [Libor transition: Building SOFR discount curve](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/61838/libor-transition-building-sofr-discount-curve)

However, I struggle to understand the below formula

[image]

What is the reason of having `LHS` as 100 i.e. the Principal?

I understand that for normal `IRS` where float rate is determined by `LIBOR` and also discount factor is LIBOR then the PV of all floating leg CFs is 100 on each CF date. But here we are talking of different kind of `Swap`, where floar CF is determined not by `LIBOR` but the daily `SOFR` fixes during the interest period.

So, are they basically the same? Why?

Secondly, what if I am building `SOFR` curve not in the start day of `Swap` (or any float CF day)? How should I change above formula? Or, in the construction of `SOFR` curve, we will only consider `SWAP` instruments that starts on the construction date?